# how can I enable jade on my application?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to follow this [Post](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-node-js-and-websockets-to-build-a-chat-service/)

My server.js is like this

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var jade = require('jade');
```

and i get this error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'jade'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/server.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

but when I do this

```
try {
jade = require('jade');
} catch (err) {
var jade = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade');
}
```

I can start the engine, but when I enter the site I see

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jade'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at new View (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:43:49)
    at Function.app.render (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:488:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
    at io.sockets.on.socket.on.socket.get.data.message (/var/www/server.js:18:7)
    at callbacks (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
```

I tried installing jade with `nmp install -g jade` and also `npm install jade --global`

But nothing... any idea what im doing wrong? Ive checked other posts here and at other sites but no result

--EDIT--

when I make npm install jade --global I get this at the end (before some http GET and http 304 that all looks fine, no warning or error)

```
/usr/local/bin/jade -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade
jade@0.35.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade
âââ character-parser@1.2.0
âââ commander@2.0.0
âââ mkdirp@0.3.5
âââ transformers@2.1.0 (promise@2.0.0, css@1.0.8, uglify-js@2.2.5)
âââ with@1.1.1 (uglify-js@2.4.0)
âââ monocle@1.1.50 (readdirp@0.2.5)
âââ constantinople@1.0.2 (uglify-js@2.4.0)
```

Comment: thank you, I added more information at my post, could you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the global install path for Node is not actually in your system path. The error in the second case is probably a subsidiary module like Express also trying to require jade.

Try a local install: assuming `jade` is in your `package.json` (it is by default, if you used the `express` command to generate a skeleton) run this in your project root:

`npm install -d`

this flag installs dependencies

Comment: Hi, I tried making npm install -d and nothing happened, just http GET but all were fine, and at the end was something like I see after install jade

Comment: I think it works because I got an structure node_module with folders and files inside

Comment: Details of where node looks for required stuff: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules